# Why can I use the same function to read YAML data from a string and a file handler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, yaml

I had to read YAML data one time from a file, and another one from a string. To my surprise, both use the same function:

```
import yaml

data = """
hello:
    world
"""
# read the string
doc = yaml.safe_load(data)
print(doc)

# write the string to a file and read the file
with open("data.yaml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
with open("data.yaml", 'r') as f:
    doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
print(doc)

# output:
# {'hello': 'world'}
# {'hello': 'world'}
```

Why is it so? In the first case the type of data passed to `yaml.safe_load()` is a `str` and in the other case `TextIOWrapper` - but both are equally accepted.

Are they so similar that they can both be user without discrimination by a function? Or is `yaml.safe_load()` internally checking what type of data it receives and dispatches the handling accordingly?

Comment: The function introspects the arguments and handles it according to its type.

Comment: Actually it could be duck-typing as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the `Reader` is [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/reader.py)

```
class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        if isinstance(stream, str):
            self.name = "<unicode string>"
            self.check_printable(stream)
            self.buffer = stream+'\0'
        elif isinstance(stream, bytes):
            self.name = "<byte string>"
            self.raw_buffer = stream
            self.determine_encoding()
        else:
            self.stream = stream
            self.name = getattr(stream, 'name', "<file>")
            self.eof = False
            self.raw_buffer = None
            self.determine_encoding()
```

So it does check the type of `stream` and will handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to parse YAML 1.2, for which you would need my ruamel.yaml. you can actually hand in a `pathlib.Path` as well, and that will be correctly opened for you.

Whereas the test for string/unicode is explicit in both PyYAML (for YAML 1.1) and ruamel.yaml (YAML 1.2 and 1.1) using `isinstance()`. The test for a `Path` is done differently, as the `pathlib` module is not available by default under Python 2 (although you can install  `pathlib2` and import `Path` from there). So if you were to do `isinstance(arg, Path)`, you would need to catch a possible exception.

Instead ruamel.yaml `load()` method, tests for the argument not having a `.read()` method, and having a `open` method, in which case it assumes the argument is a `Path`, opens it and calls itself:

```
def load(self, stream):
    if not hasattr(stream, 'read') and hasattr(stream, 'open'):
        # pathlib.Path() instance
        with stream.open('rb') as fp:
            return self.load(fp)
    # processing of string/unicode/opened_file
```

This way nowhere in the code is `pathlib` actually imported.